# Media Queries Based on Element Width Plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, media

I ran into this plugin that can apply css based on the width of an element rather than the window width https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries. The plugin is fast but works partially and has a few major bugs. Is there a similar plugin that works great and does the same?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ausi/cq-prolyfill

Answer (score 0):

Here is an element query `polyfill` (plugin) you may consider using: https://github.com/tysonmatanich/elementQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There's also EQCSS, which is a plugin that extends CSS to include Element Queries, Scoped CSS (style scoping) and introduced some special new selectors like `$parent` that lets you select the parent element of something. It works in all browsers, IE8 and up. It feels like writing CSS from the future!

Check it out! http://elementqueries.com

There are examples on the site, as well as a ton of demos of things built with it at the bottom of the page.